# How to show that the centralizer of commutator subgroup is nilpotent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> How to show that $C_G(G')$ (the  centralizer of commutator subgroup $G$) is nilpotent? ($G'$ is the commutator of group $G$.)

Comment: If you denote this subgroup by $C$, you have obviously $[C, [C,C]] \subseteq [C,[G,G]] = 1$. So $C$ is nilpotent of class at most $2$.

Comment: @Crostul Why not post as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Denote this subgroup by $C$. Then obviously you have
$$[C,[C,C]] \subseteq [C,[G,G]]=1$$
so $C$ is nilpotent of class at most two.